# Need to store Multiple Images (path) into MySQL after upload

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build my own little eCommerce CMS, and i want the expert opinion on how to handle multiple uploaded files (images).

**For Example:**

A user adds a new item, fills the necessary form data and selects `(nth)` number of images and submits. I want to know how should i handle those images data into MySQL.

one thought i have in mind is that i create a separate table `item_images` Where i assign an ID or something like `Item Code` which inputs by the user and that Item Code will be the Identification for all the images?

PS: I dont want to upload Images directly to the Database, Just the paths/links.

Please advice.

Comment: yes, and also updated my question.

Comment: This is a solved problem: have you looked into how any of the various free CMS packages work? [MediaWiki does this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images) for example.

Comment: yeah thats good but Can you tell me in a simple way?

Comment: Building your own CMS isn't a simple task.

Comment: That's what i thought, but i want to do this any ways it'll help me learning more (like this issue im having)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by creating 2 additional tables:

`Table Images ( ImageID int, ImagePath varchar )`

`Table ImagesXUsers ( UserID int, ImageID int )` (or ImagesXPages or whatever it is you need to associate these images with)

Whenever images are uploaded, they are inserted into the `Images` table, and are appropriately associated with the user account via the `ImagesXUsers` table.

An example query for retrieving all the images for a given user account could be the following:

```
SELECT i.ImageID, i.ImagePath
FROM Images i
JOIN ImagesXUsers u ON
    u.ImageID = i.ImageID AND
    u.UserID = {whatever user is logged in}
```

Comment: No problem. Are you familiar with database normalization?

Comment: Not really :( no

Comment: I highly recommend looking into it, it will save you alot of headaches when designing and dealing with a database. Check this out: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: Thank you. I'm definitely going to read that thoroughly.